# Rollback in laravel has no effect

Tags: php, database, laravel-5, eloquent, rollback

I am creating a backup system but I got an issue with the import step. **Impossible to rollback if there is any error**.

> I'm using this code on the CLI mode (via *artisan myowncommand*)

---

I have a file, with all my instructions:

```
<?php
// @generated 2016-12-11 01:05:25

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Category;
// ...

DB::beginTransaction();
  Category::truncate();
  // ...

  // LOAD MODEL `Category` (CLASS `App\Category`)
  Category::unguard();
  Category::create(array (
    'id' => 1,
    'name' => 'Holidays',
    'descr' => 'Holidays & sick & off',
    'color' => 'default',
    'created_at' => '2016-12-11 01:05:21',
    'updated_at' => '2016-12-11 01:05:21',
  ));
  // ...
  Category::reguard();

  // ...

DB::rollback();
?>
```

If I execute this code, it's like if no rollback happened :( If I clean my table and execute the script ... data are inserted.

According the laravel documentation, rollback instruction should be compatible:

> Using the DB facade's transaction methods also controls transactions
>   for the query builder and Eloquent ORM (https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/database).

I also tried to use the DB::transaction() (with manual error (changed `id` by `ida`) to trigger rollback). No difference.

Do you have any explanation ? Or any way to execute correctly the rollback instruction ?

Thanks :)

---

## Solutions I tested

### Test 1

```
try {
  DB::beginTransaction();

  include $file;
  /*** File is:
   * use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
   * use App\Category;
   * 
   * Category::truncate();
   * Category::unguard();
   * Category::create(array ('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Holidays'));
   * // create error by changing 'id' by 'ida'
   * Category::reguard();
   ***/

  DB::commit();
  echo sprintf('> Load Backup file `%s` COMPLETED', $file);
}
catch( \Exception $e ) {
  DB::rollback();
  echo sprintf('> Load file `%s` failled - ROLLBACK', $file);
  throw $e;
}
```

### Test 2

```
DB::transaction(function() {
  include $file;
  /*** File is:
   * use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
   * use App\Category;
   * 
   * Category::truncate();
   * Category::unguard();
   * Category::create(array ('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Holidays'));
   * // create error by changing 'id' by 'ida'
   * Category::reguard();
   ***/
});
```

### Test 3 & 4

Same as *test 1*, `include $file` and all `DB::transaction`, `DB::beginTransaction` & `DB::commit` & `DB:rollback` directly in this $file file

### Test 5

I tried to:

- move the DB::beginTransaction outside the try/catch
- move the DB::commit outside the try/catch

## Test case

1. `php artian migrate:refresh --seed` Clear tables & populate with some masterdata
2. On phpmyadmin, clean (truncable) table (here: category).
3. There is no result on the table
4. Execute the code. "Load Backup failled - ROLLBACK" is executed
5. On phpmyadmin, check data: there are records. *Model:truncable from my code executed, but not rollback*

Comment: Any reason why you are throwing another exception in the catch block. Doesn't it kind of create a loop of exceptions? I

Comment: I throwing the exception to use the standard error catching of Laravel. There is another level of try/catch in the core source code :)

Comment: Did you try by moving your `DB::beginTransaction()` and `DB::commit()` outside the try-catch block?

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be

```
DB::beginTransaction();
try
{
    //code for processing multiple related transactions
    include $file;
}
catch(\Exception $e)
{ 
    DB::rollBack();
    //echo error message
}
DB::commit();
//echo success message
```

`DB::beginransaction` `and DB::commit` should be outside the try-catch block. It works for me.

And your $file should have only the instructions which you want within the  try block - no DB::beginTransaction(), DB::commit() or DB::rollBack() statements.

**UPDATE**

The general logical steps to follow would be

1. Begin transaction  -  `DB::beginTransaction()`
2. Run database queries - crud operations  - `try{//run queries}`
3. If there's an error/exception - Rollback the transaction  - `catch(Exception $e){ DB::rollBack()`
4. Send/display the error/exception message   - `//display/send error/exception message }`
5. If the queries run smoothly - Commit the transaction  -  `DB::commit()`

Hope this helps.

Comment: According the way how is construct the DB:transaction, commit should be done on the try part (it's: rollback or commit; not both). Anyway, I tested this solution without result :( And yes, there is no conflict, it was for illustrate (I edited my previous post). It's working for you with DB instructions or Model:instructions ?

Comment: @GeorgesO. Yes its working for me using eloquent. I have updated the answer with logical flow for manual control of transactions. The flow works for me.

Comment: Which laravel version are you using? The rollback method is renamed to `DB::rollBack()` since L5.1 in L5.0 it was `DB::rollback()` just a little pointer to check.

Comment: Laravel Framework version 5.3.26 :) I don't think php is case sensitive for function, even static ones. I tried your solution & process, but it's not working :(

Comment: Really strange. I follow the process (flow) and it works for me. Actually I understood the flow from a good post by @fideloper at http://fideloper.com/laravel-database-transactions - you can have a look at it too.

Answer (score 0):

I was with the same problem, I start reading the documentation carefully and it was mysql version, must be 5.7+.

Answer (score 0):

some reason a rollback often requires you to run composer dump-autoload. if your migration work.

Comment: php artian migrate:fresh --seed

Comment: fresh your database